# Wrong proof...But where is the mistake?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

So I've just watched this wonderful [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seUU2bZtfgM) video about transcendental numbers.

In the video, the guy shows that

$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}=1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3}+\cdots$$

In the video, he says that if a number can be reduced to zero, it is algebraic.

Now, if we take:

$$1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3}+\cdots$$

and multiply that by 1, we can get:

$$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\cdots$$
take that and multiply by $2$, we get:

$$2+2+1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$$

Next we will get:

$$6+6+3+1+\cdots$$

And so on. Wait, isn't that something that can be reduced to zero?

Obviously there is a mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

(Just highschool student here - so take it easy :))

EDIT:

When I say reduced to zero I mean - using addition, substraction, multiplying, dividing and raising to a power of a whole number, in order to reduce the number to zero. So in the last equation, we can reduce 6, and 6 and 3 and so on.

Comment: A number is algebraic if if can be reduced to zero ? Never heard about such a claim and neither do I understand what is meant.

Comment: It is being said in the video o.O

Comment: I just watched the first bit, so I'm not sure if he addressed this there, but when  he means reduced to zero, he means using only finitely many operations

Comment: A number is algebraic if it is a solution to a polynomial with rational coefficients.

Comment: @rammus that is a definition I am familiar with. And rational can be replaced by integer. To be exact, it is not a solution to a polynomial, but a root of a polynomial $p(x)$, in other words , a solution to $p(x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the correlation between your deduction, e, and reducing to 0. This is probably just me though...

Comment: @Kbot I dont unserstand it neither :) But in the video, that math prof says that, so I figured he speaks truth.

Comment: "Reduced to zero" is an expression I've never heard before in this context. Also, I don't see how you're reducing anything to zero. If you want to prove something, you need to (a) define everything precisely (what does "reducible to zero" mean?) and (b) justify your steps (what is the connection between being algebraic, and being "reducible to zero"?).

Comment: Even a claim of a math prof is not necessarily true ... Do you have an approve of this outside the video ?

Comment: @Peter Nope - I just watched this video, and looking at wiki pages is way too complicated for me :)

Comment: It would help if you specify what you mean by "wait, isn't that something that can be reduced to zero?"  I have no idea why the sum of positive numbers can be "reduced to zero" (especially when those numbers seem to be getting _bigger_ at each step), but I am curious about your intended meaning.

Comment: Using "addition, subtraction, multiplying, dividing, raising to a power" with what numbers?  Do you mean taking the numbers in each term and arithmetically combining them in arbitrary ways?  If so, perhaps the devil is in the ... terms that you do not specify.  It also might help to give an example.  Is $3 + 3 + 6$ "reducible to 0" because $3 + 3 - 6 = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying the rules of the game clearly, but whatever they may be, the intention is that the number of steps in the game is *finite*. Your algorithm, in contrast, is *infinite*: you need to multiply the series expansion of $e$ by all positive integers in order to make all the terms integral, which doesn't make much sense.

It is somewhat hard, though not impossible, to define "algebraic" along the lines of your game. One definition would be as follows. A "reduction of $x$ to zero" is any computation involving $x$, rational numbers, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division (but not by zero!), and raising to an integer power, whose result is zero. It is *non-trivial* if there is some other number $y$ so that if you repeat the very same computation then you *don't* get zero. A number is algebraic if it has a non-trivial reduction to zero.

Using induction you can show that a number $x$ is algebraic if and only if there exist rationals $a_0,\ldots,a_n$, *not all zero*, so that
$$ a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots a_n x^n = 0. $$
Hermite proved that $e$ doesn't satisfy any such equation, and his proof has since been simplified, though there it's still not very very simple.

What does the proof look like? We can start with an easier target: showing that $e$ is not rational. Here the proof is reasonable simple. Suppose that $e = p/q$, and multiply the series expansion of $e$ by $q!$ to get
$$
(q-1)! p = \frac{q!}{0!} + \frac{q!}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{q!}{q!} + \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)(q+2)} + \cdots.
$$
Since $p,q$ are integers, this implies that
$$
\frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)(q+2)} + \cdots
$$
is an integer. However,
$$
0 < \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)(q+2)} + \cdots < \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)^2} + \cdots = 1/q \leq 1,
$$
and we reach a contradiction.

The proof that $e$ isn't algebraic is much more complicated, and can be viewed [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Herstein%20Beweis%20der%20Transzendenz%20der%20Zahl%20e.pdf) as well as in many other places on the web.

Comment: _the number of steps in the game is finite_ - yup, that is it. In the video, he says nothing about finite operations, so I though it is allowed :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't define clearly what "reduced to zero" means. It appears you are at least allowed to multiply by integers and add/subtract integers.  With just these operations you can reduce any rational number to zero.  If the number is $\frac ab$, you can multiply by $b$ and subtract $a$ to get to zero.

For algebraic numbers, you also need to be allowed to raise to powers and add/subtract previous results.  The algebraic numbers are the solutions of polynomials with integer coefficients. For example, $\sqrt 2$ is algebraic as it satisfies $x^2-2=0$ You can reduce it to zero by squaring and subtracting $2$.  For a more complicated example, $x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+6$ has a [single real root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2B2*x%5E4%2B3*x%5E3%2B4*x%5E2%2B5*x%2B6%3D0) near $-1.5$  With integer powers, integer multiplies, and integer addition you can reduce it to zero just by following the polynomial.

That dot dot dot at the end of you last expression hides the fact that there are infinitely many terms, so you cannot reduce $e$ to zero with this approach.  No matter what you multiply by, there will still be infinitely many fractions off the right end.  This does not prove that there is not another way to do it, but in fact there is not.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) says this was proved by Charles Hermite in 1873.

Comment: I finally got the meaning of "reduce to zero" from your answer.