# What is a transcendental function?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

I was learning about partial fractions, and the lecturer started talking about partial fractions with a transcendental denominator. What is a transcendental function?

Comment: @LeeMosher True. I'll turn it into two separate questions.

Comment: not a root of an algebraic equation; e.g., $e^x, \sin x, \ln x$

Comment: A transcendental function is a function that is not an algebraic function. As for what an algebraic function is, see [Precise definition of an “algebraic function”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813115/13130). See also [What is transcendental equation/function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333916/13130) *AND* [In simple English, what does it mean to be transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1686156/13130) *AND* [Proof that $e^x$ is a transcendental function of $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186752/13130).